# Chrome Not Applying GPO Policies

Tags: group-policy, google-chrome

I'm having a little trouble getting Chrome installions on our workstation to update it's policies to reflect I've sent in GPO.

I added the admx and adml to %systemroot%\policyDefinitions as our Server is Server 2012 and all the workstations are Win 7.

I've tried adding the settings to the both the Computer Config and User Config but neither seem to work.

I've tried the Chrome for Work MSI and the normal user installer but again nothing.

[image]

Comment: Can you tell us what policy change you're trying?

Comment: I forgot people use imgur...
http://i.imgur.com/dyPzgBR.jpg

Comment: It may also be helpful to see the relevant snips of `gpresult /r` to verify the GPO is in-scope and applying. Errors noted in `rsop.msc` may help too.

Comment: gpresult: http://pastebin.com/1frvA4YS

Comment: After editing out the identifiers of my account I found what I thought would be the issue which is that I'm not in the same OU as the people on in the location.
So I transferred our test account over to the OU and ran a gpupdate /force and ran the gpresult /r again and it's showing the Chrome GPO is moving but Chrome is still say no policies set.
gpresult: http://pastebin.com/xsXp2Ctx